# Best way for frequent view change in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android app, it's a turn-based game. I have two types of turns (let's say `TypeA` and `TypeB`) and UI for `TypeA` is completely different from UI for `TypeB`. Also, there are sub-types for `TypeB`, each of them having their own UI. Every UI is implemented with a `Fragment`, but for a single game I need to create about 30 fragments, each of them used just a single time. 
Currently I create the `Fragment`, save the data I need, destroy the fragment with

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(myFragment).commit()
```

and then I create the next `Fragment` and so on. Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is the right way, add fragments only when you need it and remove whose do not need.

Anyway I can suggest you to try `Navigation Component` to check visually all your fragments flow.

Ref. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started